# meaning of "it goes around my heart"

Tags: meaning

Pop singer Sandra has a song Around My Heart where she sings "it goes around my heart". What is the meaning? Is it somehow related to what goes around comes around?

EDIT for more context:

> ```
> one kiss on a flatbed truck
> a hot rain
> has completed our love
> you said
> words don't mean nothing
> but you will be mine
>
> IT GOES AROUND MY HEART
>
> hey hey what a criminal man
> life will go in circles
> all around my heart
> hey hey
> it's such a dangerous game
> i'm afraid
> you'd lose your trust in love
> ```

Comment: Having more context would be helpful. Would you please edit your question to add more of the lyric surrounding the phrase you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: The meaning may be similar to how a necklace "goes around your neck" (i.e., "is meant for wearing on your neck"). Without more context, however, I don't know.

Comment: [related meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/why-only-some-questions-asking-lyrics-meaning-are-off-topic-and-not-all)

Comment: I don't see an obvious, unambiguous meaning in these lyrics.  You'll have to ask the lyricist.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, where did you dig that up...

No, seriously. You need to remember that this song was written in the 80's from a team of german songwriters. It sounds a bit like a too-direct translation from German. Hard to explain, actually, as I can't really point on what triggers my "native speaker senses".

> It goes around in my heart.

Which *could* then be read as:

> It troubles my heart. / It moves my heart.

But as with most songs, there is *a lot* of room for interpretation.

Comment: I agree that we may have to look to German idiom to figure out a reasonable meaning. The phrase "goes around" could mean "encircle" or it could mean "orbit" (from the second stanza). It reminds me of the time that a German friend said to me "my butt is on my feet" to mean (I think) "I'm really tired".